# TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable error

Tags: python

This is basic code, but it is throwing a 'TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable' on the "print(numList[index])." Can someone please help me get rid of this error.

```py
numbers = input("Enter 9 Numbers: ")
numList = (int(x) for x in numbers.split())

index = 0
for count in range(0, 10):
    if count % 3 == 0:
        print(numList[index])
    else:
        print(numList[index])
    index+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

To make `numList` an array instead of a generator change the brackets from `(` to `[`

```
numList = [int(x) for x in numbers.split()]
```

Regardless of whether it is an array or a generator you can iterate over the `numList` like the following

```
for num in numList:
    if num % 3 == 0:
        print("{} is multiple of 3".format(num))
    else:
        print("{} is not multiple of 3".format(num))
```

Answer (score 0):

The error was being thrown when I was converting the string input into an integer list. To fix it, I used a loop and converted each index into an integer.

Answer (score 0):

The line:
`numList = (int(x) for x in numbers.split())`

Creates a generator, which only returns a single value each time it is called (see https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/).

What you probably want is a list comprehension, which will create a new list that you can index:
`numList = [int(x) for x in numbers.split()]`

Once you do this, you'll notice that your range goes beyond the length of `numList` (9), but that's also an easy fix:

`for count in range(0, 9):`

Another option would be to keep the generator and do something like this:

```
numbers = input("Enter 9 Numbers: ")
numList = (int(x) for x in numbers.split())

for count, num in enumerate(numList):
    if count % 3 == 0:
        print(num)
    else:
        print(num) #eventually you what to do something different here?
```